# c# all posible combinations of number and identify each

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I have a code, working, which finds all possible combinations of numbers equal to 18. I want to implement it in my program,
The problem is that I need to identify each one of those numbers, because some of them are repeated. then the program operates with them separately.

Specifically I have a set of weights and locations, each location has a weight attached to it.

I need to find the combination of these locations, which do not exceed a certain weight, and then go to them one by one.

The problem is that if in two locations the weight is the same as I identify it to go first to one location and then to another.

Thanks a lot!

```
        int[] set = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2}; //weights

        foreach (string s in GetCombinations(set, 18, "")) //18 max weight
        {
            textBox1.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
        }



    public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(int[] set, int sum, string values)
        {            

        for (int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
            {
                int left = sum - set[i];
                string vals = set[i] + "," + values;
                if (left == 0)
                {
                    yield return vals;
                }
                else
                {
                    int[] possible = set.Take(i).Where(n => n <= sum).ToArray();
                    if (possible.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string s in GetCombinations(possible, left, vals))
                        {
                            yield return s;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If the weight is in the list multiple times, can it be used multiple times in the combination?

Comment: No, only one time. i reach the location one time, and after that  is eliminated

Comment: Not the location, the weight at that location. In your example data, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2 add up to 14 which is less than 18. Should that combination be returned